# How to send a message to every single connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I know that in ActionCable the ping works this way:

```
def beat
  transmit type: ActionCable::INTERNAL[:message_types][:ping], message: Time.now.to_i
end
```

But when I try to transmit on connect, only one connecton gets my message with `transmit` why?

```
def connect
  self.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
  transmit({'title': 'players_online', 'message': 'A new user has been subscribed'})
end
```

Comment: Maybe only one subscriber? Check who subscribed.

Comment: @Sylar 3 subscribers

Comment: Update the post with more code so I can replicate.

Comment: where is your client code? are you subscribing to the message everywhere?

Comment: @maxpleaner I am subscribing from iOS using SocketRocket

Comment: @ViktorDanilov are you ruling out that the problem is there?

Comment: @maxpleaner I see the application console. Other iOS clients get only ping messages and only the one who connected got actual `transmit` message.

Comment: @ViktorDanilov maybe you could try to have `connect` send your data through a ping message? But that's the last of my advice, I haven't actually used actioncable.

Comment: @maxpleaner I don't wnat to touch libs code to do that

Comment: What? How are you going to fix the big if you can't change code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually very easy:

```
ActionCable.server.connections.each do |connection|
  connection.transmit({'title': 'players_online', 'message': ActionCable.server.connections.size})
end
```